# How to use Python to catch a web page response from another browser tab?

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, instagram

I'm currently making an script that allows to download Instagram stories from any private account that you follow. The best tool I've found so far is [this](https://instafinsta.com/private-downloader) webpage which uses your account session from the web browser to get the content.

The thing is that when this site gets the query response with all the stories information it automatically opens a new tab in the browser with all the content in JSON format.

Example:
If you enter the url with the requested stories (such as https://www.instagram.com/stories/highlights/1234567890/) a new tab will be opened with plain text like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "reels_media": [
      {
        "__typename": "GraphHighlightReel",
        "id": "some_id",
        "latest_reel_media": null,
        "owner": {
          "__typename": "GraphUser",
          "id": "some_id",
          "profile_pic_url": "some_url",
          "username": "some_username"
        },
        "items": [
          {
            "__typename": "GraphStoryVideo",
            "id": "some_id",
            "dimensions": { "height": 1136, "width": 640 },
            "display_resources": [
              {
                "src": "some_url",
                "config_width": 640,
                "config_height": 1136
              },
              {
                "src": "some_url",
                "config_width": 750,
                "config_height": 1331
              },
...
```

And when you copy-paste all the JSON content in the "Paste alien text here..." box you get all the media displayed to download directly.

What I'm doing right now is download the result HTML file with the media and then pass it to my script to download the stuff. But what I want to do is to catch the response directly inside the script using some kind of "fake browser" module. The problem is that I don't know how to get the response if the content is opened in a different tab.

If needed I can post part of my script to show how it works right now.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: So, you want to scrape things from a website?

Comment: Yes, I guess this would be called web scrapping. I've been using another tool called instaloader (https://instaloader.github.io/) which makes queries using the Instagram API but is much slower and is limited to a certain amount of queries daily if I'm not wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`selenium`](https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=https://pypi.org/project/selenium/&ulang=de)

> Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.
> Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should) also be automated as well.

##### Example:

- open a new Firefox browser
- load the Yahoo homepage
- search for “seleniumhq”
- close the browser

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```